# Olá preciso saber como gerar arquivos Csv e como implementar o gerador de arquivos nesse código

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-excel

Esse código é uma atividade do meu curso onde soma a nota de 2 alunos e depois é necessário gerar um arquivo csv no excel com o relatório desses alunos, pesquisei muito e não consegui encontrar conteúdo atualizado se alguem tiver alguma recomendação desde já fico grato.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using CsvHelper;

namespace Definitivo_Desafio_05
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Lista
            List<Aluno> listaAluno = new List<Aluno>();

            Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
            aluno.Nome = "José";
            aluno.Nota = 8;


            Aluno aluno2 = new Aluno();
            aluno2.Nome = "José";
            aluno2.Nota = 7;

            listaAluno.Add(aluno);
            foreach (Aluno aluno1 in listaAluno)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A soma da nota dos alunos é: " + (aluno.Nota + aluno2.Nota));
            }

            foreach (Aluno item in listaAluno)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(aluno);
                Console.WriteLine(aluno2);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para escrever o conteúdo da lista de alunos em um arquivo csv você pode utilizar o `File.WriteAllLines()` mas para isto precisará transformar a lista em um `IEnumerable`:

```cs
IEnumerable<string> alunos = listaAluno.Select(aluno => (string) aluno);
```

Note que estamos selecionando os registros da `listaAluno` e transformando em um string através do `(string) aluno`. Para que isto funcione, dentro da classe  `Aluno` é necessário criar um método que retorne uma string com as propriedades da classe. No meu caso eu fiz com [implicit operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators):

```cs
public static implicit operator string(Aluno aluno) => $"{aluno.Nome},{aluno.Nota}";
```

Depois de adicionar o método acima à classe `Aluno` podemos passar o path (caminho) de onde desejamos salvar o arquivo e a lista de alunos que geramos anteriormente através de parâmetros do `File.WriteAllLines()`:

```cs
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:/arquivo.csv", alunos);
```

Se você seguir corretamente estes passos e executar o programa. Ao visitar o diretório que passou no método acima, você verá o arquivo csv gerado.

Nota: Eu utilizei a versão 6.0.7 do .NET como referência para escrever estes trechos de exemplo.

Answer (score -3):

Um arquivo CSV, Comma-Separated Values (valores separados por vírgula), é um arquivo, como o próprio nome diz, cujos valores de uma linha são separados por algum delimitador (como a vírgula, ponto e vírgula etc.).
Gere um arquivo com linhas com os seguintes valores:

```
nota1 do aluno A;nota2 do aluno A;soma do aluno A
nota1 do aluno B;nota2 do aluno B;soma do aluno B
...
```

Ex:

```
5.0;3.0;8.0
2.0;1.0;3.0
...
```

Você poderá abrir esse arquivo no Excel e ele conseguirá colocar cada valor em uma coluna diferente.